# How to Post facebook update from Android app using Facebook SDK 4.0?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

Currently , I'm developing android app which needs to have an functionality where user can share some text as Post update on Facebook . I found one example which works perfectly to post on facebook but it uses older version of facebook sdk . Here is link of that example : http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-example . This example works with facebook SDK 3.19.1 version.

Firstly , I'm using current Facebook SDK version 4+ & not able to find answers for my doubt:

1. Do I need to include Facebook Login module to Post update on Facebook ?

Secondly , I have listview which has a share button which should allow user to share that message on facebook. Here is screenshot of screen:

[image]

In above screen , allow user to share above message on their facebook wall.

I'm using CursorAdpater to display above list so , I have implemented onClick event for Share button in my CursorAdpater class to perform sharing operation .

I know some of you found this question is duplicate but I have searched many resources which are deprecated from SDK verion 4.0 & haven't found any concrete solution to this question . So , just read my entire question before marking / closing  this question as duplicate .

Any example / references would be appreciated.

Comment: check this link it will help you https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Comment: @PradeepGupta gone through it but it only shows sharing videos , links , photos but no example for Posting text / message on Facebook wall of user. 
They provided steps on Custom Interface within Advance Topics but no example .

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", "This is a test message");
/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/me/feed",
    params,
    HttpMethod.POST,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

and check this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/user/feed